# tabular indentation won't go away, even with \noindent and @{} in tabular preamble

Tags: tables, threeparttable, aastex

I keep trying to get my table to not indent but nothing works.

Here is my header:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{aastex62}

\usepackage[para]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{rotating}
```

Here is my table:

```
\begin{table}[h]
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Geometries and final energies (not included ZPE, although could include that easily) for CO3(C2v).}
\noindent\begin{tabular}{@{}l|lllll}
Level of theory & r(C=O) & R(c-o) & A(OCO) ext &R(O-O) & Ref\\
 & & &{[}A(OCO) int{]}& &\\
\hline
CCSD(2)T/cc-pVTZ & 1.1752 & 1.3328 & 142.83 {[}74.34{]} & 1.61051 & \tnote{a} \\
CCSD(2)T/6-311+G(d) & 1.1774 & 1.3327 & 142.12 {[}75.76{]} & 1.6366 & \tnote{a} \\
B3LYP/aug-cc-pVQZ & 1.1691 & 1.3306 & 143.62 {[}72.75{]} & 1.5783 & \tnote{a} \\
B3LYP/6-311+G(d) & 1.17 & 1.33 &  & 1.59 & \tnote{c} \\
PBE/aug-cc-pVQZ & 1.1804 & 1.3432 & 143.56 {[}72.87{]} & 1.5956 & \tnote{a} \\
MP2/aug-cc-pVQZ & 1.1752 & 1.3354 & 143.07 {[}73.85{]} & 1.6046 & \tnote{a} \\
SCS-MP2/aug-cc-pVQZ & 1.1740 & 1.3340 & 142.82 {[}74.35{]} & 1.6121 & \tnote{a} \\
CASSCF(16,13)/6-311G(d) & 1.174 & 1.337 & {[}77.2{]} & 1.668 & \tnote{e} \\
CASSCF(8,8)/6-311+G(d) & 1.15 & 1.31 &  & 1.66 & \tnote{c} \\
MP2/cc-pVTZ & 1.1743 & 1.3330 & {[}73.84{]} & 1.6014 & \tnote{b} \\
CCSD/cc-pVTZ & 1.1663 & 1.3211 & {[}73.33{]} & 1.5777 & \tnote{b} \\
CCSD(T)/cc-pVTZ & 1.1728 & 1.3296 & {[}74.95{]} & 1.6179 & \tnote{b} \\
CCSD(T)/6-311+G(d) & 1.18 & 1.33 &  & 1.65 & \tnote{c}\\
MRCI+Q(16/10)/cc-pVTZ & 1.1718 & 1.3252 & 142.2 &  & \tnote{d} \\
BCCD(T)/cc-pVTZ & 1.1758 & 1.3333 & 142.6 &  & \tnote{d} \\
CCSD(TQ)/cc-pVTZ & 1.1745 & 1.3324 & 142.4 &  & \tnote{d} \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\begin{tablenotes}
\footnotesize
\item [a] Present Data
\item [b] \cite{kowalczyk2007electronic}
\item [c] \cite{elliott2005oxygen}
\item [d] \cite{liu2009combined}
\item [e] \cite{mebel2004theoretical} ??
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
```

Here is what my table looks like :
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: I think `aastex62` is the problem because with an ordinary `article` class it works. Unfortunately, I can't solve it.

Comment: You might want to use the `deluxetable` environment provided by the `aastex62` dcumentclass.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The documentation of `aastex` recommends to use their `deluxetable` environment. (See [Section 2.16 Tables](https://journals.aas.org/aastexguide/#tables))

> There is support in the AASTeX package for tables via two mechanisms:
>   LATEX’s standard `table` environment, and the `deluxetable`
>   environment, which allows for the formatting of lengthy tabular
>   material. Tables may be marked up using either mechanism, although use
>   of `deluxetable` is preferred.

With the use of the `deluxetable` environment the caption is automatically as wide as the table and one can also add a variety of different table notes. It therefore seems to offer all of the features that you used with the `threeparttable` package.

Here is a MWE that shows how xou could use the `deluxetable` environment for your table. For the table notes, I have included examples of three different commands that can be used: `\tablenotetext`, `\tablerefs` and `\tablecomments`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{aastex62}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{gensymb}


\begin{document}

\begin{deluxetable}{l|lllll}
\tablecaption{Geometries and final energies (not included ZPE, although could include that easily) for CO3(C2v).}
\tablehead{\colhead{Level of theory} & \colhead{r(C=O)} & \colhead{R(c-o)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{1.9cm}}{A(OCO) ext  {[}A(OCO) int{]}} & \colhead{R(O-O)} & \colhead{Ref}}
\startdata
CCSD(2)T/cc-pVTZ & 1.1752 & 1.3328 & 142.83 {[}74.34{]} & 1.61051 & \tablenotemark{a} \\
CCSD(2)T/6-311+G(d) & 1.1774 & 1.3327 & 142.12 {[}75.76{]} & 1.6366 & \tablenotemark{a} \\
B3LYP/aug-cc-pVQZ & 1.1691 & 1.3306 & 143.62 {[}72.75{]} & 1.5783 & \tablenotemark{a} \\
B3LYP/6-311+G(d) & 1.17 & 1.33 &  & 1.59 & \tablenotemark{c} \\
PBE/aug-cc-pVQZ & 1.1804 & 1.3432 & 143.56 {[}72.87{]} & 1.5956 & \tablenotemark{a} \\
MP2/aug-cc-pVQZ & 1.1752 & 1.3354 & 143.07 {[}73.85{]} & 1.6046 & \tablenotemark{a} \\
SCS-MP2/aug-cc-pVQZ & 1.1740 & 1.3340 & 142.82 {[}74.35{]} & 1.6121 & \tablenotemark{a} \\
CASSCF(16,13)/6-311G(d) & 1.174 & 1.337 & {[}77.2{]} & 1.668 & \tablenotemark{e} \\
CASSCF(8,8)/6-311+G(d) & 1.15 & 1.31 &  & 1.66 & \tablenotemark{c} \\
MP2/cc-pVTZ & 1.1743 & 1.3330 & {[}73.84{]} & 1.6014 & \tablenotemark{b} \\
CCSD/cc-pVTZ & 1.1663 & 1.3211 & {[}73.33{]} & 1.5777 & \tablenotemark{b} \\
CCSD(T)/cc-pVTZ & 1.1728 & 1.3296 & {[}74.95{]} & 1.6179 & \tablenotemark{b} \\
CCSD(T)/6-311+G(d) & 1.18 & 1.33 &  & 1.65 & \tablenotemark{c}\\
MRCI+Q(16/10)/cc-pVTZ & 1.1718 & 1.3252 & 142.2 &  & \tablenotemark{d} \\
BCCD(T)/cc-pVTZ & 1.1758 & 1.3333 & 142.6 &  & \tablenotemark{d} \\
CCSD(TQ)/cc-pVTZ & 1.1745 & 1.3324 & 142.4 &  & \tablenotemark{d} \\
\enddata
\tablenotetext{a}{Present Data} 
\tablenotetext{b}{\cite{kowalczyk2007electronic}}
\tablenotetext{c}{\cite{elliott2005oxygen}}
\tablenotetext{d}{\cite{liu2009combined}}
\tablenotetext{e}{\cite{mebel2004theoretical} ??}
\tablerefs{\cite{kowalczyk2007electronic}}
\tablecomments{\textsuperscript{a}Present Data, \textsuperscript{b}\cite{kowalczyk2007electronic}, \textsuperscript{c}\cite{elliott2005oxygen}, \textsuperscript{d}\cite{liu2009combined}, \textsuperscript{e}\cite{mebel2004theoretical} ??}
\end{deluxetable}



\end{document}
```

---

Lastly, some more comments:

If `C=O` refers to a carbon-oxygen-double bond, you might want to use `C\dbond O` instead. The same applies to `O-O` vs. `O\sbond O`. (See section [2.18.2 Ionic Species and Chemical Bonds](https://journals.aas.org/aastexguide/#ionic_species)):

> For single, double, and triple chemical bonds, use the following
>   macros.
>
> ```
> \sbond
>
> \dbond
>
> \tbond
> ```

If `C2v` refers to the point group / symmetry oparator it might be useful to follow the IUPAC recommendations that are [discussed for example here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/32939).

If `CO3` refers to the carbonate anion, you might want to add the `mhchem` package and use `\ce{CO3^{2-}}` to a) make the `3` a subscript and b) include the carge of the anion as a superscript.